# Passed by reference or copy ArrayList

Tags: android, android-activity, reference, copy

when I share an array list from the Main Activity to an Custom View for example will it be passed by reference or copy, my doubt is if the MainActivity add new elements to this list that was passed the Custom View will get the change. I want to build an application that the main activity will be processing a lot of data and putting this in an array, this array will be passed to a custom view that through canvas will draw a graph with the information inside of the list that was passed, so that is why this information is so important. Any kind of help will be precious, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is passed by reference yes. All objects are. You can read all about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Cheers Bojan, I am still implementing here so that means I can carry on with the ideas I had before to implement this application